# Jquery function display different alerts at the same time setInterval

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I have this function, which shows alerts of an especific value each 2 seconds.

```
jQuery.fn.ShowAlert = function(value){
   var value=value;
       setInterval( function(){alert(value);},2000)

 }

 $("#show1").on("click", function(){  $(document).ShowAlert(4);});
 $("#show2").on("click", function(){  $(document).ShowAlert(3);});
 $("#show3").on("click", function(){  $(document).ShowAlert(2);}); 

       $(document).ShowAlert(4); /*by default the page start alerting the number 4*/
```

So anytime I click an anchor, the page starts popping up alerts of the value selected each 2 seconds.

```
 <a id=show1>Show value 4</a>
 <a id=show2>Show value 3</a>
 <a id=show3>Show value 2</a>
```

the problem is, once I click more than one anchor, the function start popping up different alerts displaying the value 4 & 3 or 4 & 2 or 4,3 & 2, etc.

The question is how do I stop this behaviour? What I want is to click an anchor and the function displays alerts of the number selected only. https://jsfiddle.net/vyucptve/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear interval using `clearInterval` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)) function to start fresh when you click on a different link. Something like this can do the trick.

```
var myInterval;
jQuery.fn.ShowAlert = function(value){
   var value = value;
   if(myInterval) {
       clearInterval(myInterval);
       myInterval = null;
   }
   myInterval = setInterval( function(){alert(value);},2000)
}
```

Comment: thanks you, So what I understand is  that this behaviour is just becouse of setInterval() and nothing else? the solution would be given by clearing it?

Comment: Yes. You got it right. If you no longer require an already set interval, you need to clear it, or your next and current interval would run altogether creating unwanted behaviour. (Also, accept the answer if found helpful.)

Comment: Thanks you I have already a doubt left. What happen if instead of `setInterval( function(){alert(value);},2000)` I would put just `alert(value)` . in this case the alert would pop up, in one moment, a prior number instead of the right one or never?

Comment: In that case, it will show each alert only once (but right away). You're using `setInterval` in order to do something at regular interval.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.fn.ShowAlert = function(value){
   var value=value;

   var timerId = setInterval( function()
    {
        alert(value);
        value = value-1;
        if(value<1) {
            clearInterval(timerId);
        }

    },2000)



 }

   $(document).ShowAlert(4);     
});
</script>

<a id="show1">Show value 4</a>
<a id="show2">Show value 3</a>
<a id="show3">Show value 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The setInterval function returns a number that is a reference to that interval. You can stop an interval by calling clearInterval and passing in the reference to the previous interval.